# Formula to calculate sum of items in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have items in a row (item 1, item 2, etc...) and prices for every item in a column, can I write a **sophisticated formula** which will calculate the total for every person, without manually entering all intersection?

```
| Name   | Total   | item 1 | item 2 | item 3 |                 |    |
|--------|---------|--------|--------|--------|-----------------|----|
| John   | 2+9+2=13| 1      | 3      | 2      | price of item 1 | $2 |
| Daniel | 0+6+1=7 | 0      | 2      | 1      | price of item 2 | $3 |
| Max    | 2+3+0=5 | 1      | 1      | 0      | price of item 3 | $1 |
```

[Link to Google Spreadsheet with the example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJYOG7F0G7nUW_HrBf-bgSUtuMWJLVmBLPi_ej3QYdQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Unfortunately, I can't use scripting here, otherwise, it would be a peace of cake :(

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0, [link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJYOG7F0G7nUW_HrBf-bgSUtuMWJLVmBLPi_ej3QYdQ/edit?usp=sharing) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a alternative solution, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), mmult(--C2:E, G2:G4),))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain please what does it mean `--C2:E` it's single part which I can't find by googling

Comment: The double minus, also known as double unary, is an operation to convert Boolean values into ones and zeroes. Simply; TRUE to one (1) and FALSE to zero (0). As MMULT expects numeric values, it will return an error if any of the cells are empty. The double unary used here fills those empty cells with a zero.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 MMULT(HLOOKUP(C1:E1, TRANSPOSE(G2:H), 2, 0)*C2:E, 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(C:E)))^0)))
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(1*C2:E, G2:G4)))
```

[image]

Comment: @Anatoly https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fgVdxe19avxCwEunkrAlV2KTdRnvaYtPV2XpmNM_kYU/edit#gid=0

Comment: sorry but the second answer is much shorter and easy to understand/reuse

Comment: @Anatoly note that on 2nd answer items in F column needs to be in the same order as items on row 1 - otherwise it won't work

Comment: it's the same order because I create it by using `TRANSPOSE` formula from the row. In any case my respect, it looks very scary what you have done. Will show my coworkers when they will complain that TypeScript is difficult language :)

Comment: @Anatoly `--C2:E` is equivalent to `1*C2:E` or `N(C2:E)` - reason is that MMULT works only with numbers so empty cells needs to be converted into zeros

Comment: Thank you. What does `INDEX` do here, it returns offset by providing 3 parameters according to doc, no?

Comment: INDEX is type of ARRAYFORMULA - no benefits, its just shorter to type